# Shift + Tab not working with UpdatePanel in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

My project is in asp.net. 
In my page I have several dropdown lists. Autopost back event is fired when first data in first drop down list is selected.
After AutoPostBack, Shift + Tab not working properly.
There is Update Panel on the page.

Answer (score 1):

This likely has less to do with UpdatePanel and more to do with the browser you're using and any plugins installed.  Start removing / disabling each plugin one by one until the problem goes away.  If the problem persists, switch browsers to see if other browsers have the same issue.

I believe there's a way to start IE in "safe mode".  Try that first to see if it resolves the issue.  There's also a backward compatibility switch in IE8/7 so try that as well.

Here's a report that Windows Live toolbar causes an issue with Shift+Tab in IE.
http://forums.devshed.com/windows-help-34/shift-tab-stopped-working-in-internet-explorer-7t-569295.html